# confused about volume.

Tags: geometry, volume

I have a cylindrical container with a radius of `60mm` and a height of `58.8mm`

when I work out the volume I get ~ $665000mm^3$ which is something like $665 m^3$.

This container is really small. I can't understand how `665m` can be a measure describing something this small. Can someone help me better understand what I'm looking at here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conversion factor is wrong.   A cubic meter is NOT 1000 cubic millimeters.   You have to start with "1 meter=1000 millimeters", then cube each side,  so you get 1 cubic meter=$1000^3$ millimeters,  or 1 cubic =1000000000 cubic millimeters.

Your number is way, way smaller than 1 cubic meter :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for the fact that there are $(10^3)^3$ $mm^3$ per $m^3$.